# Expected value of a four-sided die

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

The question of this problem is asking to find the expected value for the following:

> Roll a four-sided die, double your result, then add $7$.

*(We're using a four-sided die, not actually rolling one)*.

This is the explanation shown in class, which had me confused (it's discrete uniform distribution);

**$E(X)=a+b/2$**, *where $a=1$ and $b=4$*

and then,

**$y=2x+7$** *because I have to double and then add seven*

But from here, it goes like this;

**$E(Y) = E(2x+7)$**

which is then equal to;

**= $2E(x)+7$**

Can someone explain this part to me? Does this part even work?

---

And then from my understanding, since I want to find the expected value of a four-sided die, would it make sense to do this;

$(1*(1/4)) + (2*(1/4)) + (3*(1/4)) + (4*(1/4)) = 2.5$ *since each of the numbers are all equally likely to occur.*

If I am to use the **$2E(x)+7$** from above, is this the correct equation;

$2(2.5)+7$ ?

Comment: Expectation is linear in the sense that $\mathbb{E}[aX+bY+c]=a\mathbb{E}[X]+b\mathbb{E}[Y]+c$ for the random variables $X,Y$ and numbers $a,b,c$ provided all these expectations are finite

Comment: $12$ is the correct answer

Comment: In general the expected value of equally likely terms of an arithmetic progression (their average) is the average of the first and last term: your teacher may have used this short cut to write $\frac{1+4}{2}$ rather than $1\times \frac14 +2\times \frac14 +3 \times \frac14 +4 \times \frac14$

Answer (score 1):

$(1*(1/4)) + (2*(1/4)) + (3*(1/4)) + (4*(1/4)) = 2.5$ is completely correct.

As $E[X] = \sum xP(x)$ and is since this is the uniform distribution.
$P(x) = \frac 14 $if $x\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $0$ otherwise.

$E[X] = \frac 14 \sum_\limits{x=1}^4 x$

With uniform distribution, we can take the a short cut of adding the highest and the lowest and dividing by 2.

As for the next part $E[2X+7] = 2E[X] + 7$ you can do this because of what is called "linearity of expectation."

which means that $E[X+Y] = E[X]+E[Y]$
and $E[aX] = aE[X]$

It is good to ask if this is operation is acceptable.

and we can can go back to the definition:

$E[2X+7] = \frac 14 \sum_\limits{x=1}^4 (2x + 7) = \frac 14 (2\sum_\limits{x=1}^4 x) + 7$

and see that this property indeed holds.